# Play Framework! (1.2.4): null first several dynamic parameters

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-1.x

I have such line in my `routes` file:

```
GET     /api/blahblahblah/{aaa}/{bbb}/{ccc}     Application.process
```

And I have a controller `Application` with method `process`:

> public static void process(String aaaParam, String aaaParam, String ccc) { ... }

So I access the controller this way: `http://localhost:9000/api/blahblahblah/one/two/three`

The problem is that inside this method only `ccc` parameter has it's value ("three" in this case), `aaa` and `bbb` always are `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my bad. I've figured out the reason of NPE by myself. The thing is that method params names should exactly match the routes params names: parameters don't correspond by order (as I thought), but by **name**.